# event.pageX - this.offsetLeft = -1 in chrome if margin is 0 auto

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, margin

I would like to get the mouse coordinates over canvas, that is positioned to center.

If the body width is even it works as expected, otherwise I can get -1 as result.

Take a look at this:

[image: -1 result]

(Arrow represents the cursor)
http://jsbin.com/ibumar/1/

The reason is probably related to rounding. How would you recommend to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with Chrome. I user Firefox (in Ubuntu) and I didn't have the problem. I zoomed in a bit and I still couldn’t get it (wrong).
In Chrome I tried it and there it showed me `-1` too.

console output Chrome: (closest)

```
e.pageX   this.offsetLeft
912       913
```

console output Firefox: (closest)

```
913       913
```

Answer (score 0):

If I examined `this.getBoundingClientRect().left` I figured out that it can have half value like:  `0.5`.